# Saxon 10 by default considering given input parameter as a string

Tags: xpath, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, saxon, saxparser

I have updated Saxon from version9 to version10. But for the same Xsl code getting different result.
In Saxon10 by default its considering input parameter as string, But in Saxon9 its considering input parameter as number value.
This is the expected behavior or something is wrong with input?

````
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8"/>    
<xsl:param name="var.variable1"/>    
<xsl:template match="/">     
<result>       
<xsl:choose>         
<xsl:when test="(/TestData/amount &lt; number($var.variable1) or /TestData/amount = number($var.variable1))">           <CompValue>true</CompValue>         
</xsl:when>          
<xsl:otherwise>           
<CompValue>false</CompValue>         
</xsl:otherwise>       
</xsl:choose>        
<amount>         
<xsl:value-of select="/TestData/amount/text()"/>       
</amount>       
 <var1>         
<xsl:value-of select="number($var.variable1)"/>      
</var1>    
</result> 
</xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>```


Input data:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TestData><amount>555</amount></TestData>

Saxon 9 Output:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result><CompValue>false</CompValue><amount>555</amount><var1>NaN</var1></result>

Saxon 10 Output:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result><CompValue>true</CompValue><amount>555</amount><var1>NaN</var1></result>
````

Comment: Please be more specific as to which versions eaxactly you use (e.g. 9.9 versus 10.9). And also show us exactly how you pass the parameter value to Saxon i.e. show the exact command line or the exact Java code you have.

Comment: Saxon version 9.1 versus 10.6

Comment: And how exactly do you pass the parameter? And anyway, XSLT 2/3 allows you to use typed variables and parameters with the `as` attribute, so perhaps, once you know, what kind of value you want to pass and how to construct such a value, the code will work as you need.

Comment: Saxon 9.1 is a VERY long time ago (2009), and a lot has changed in fifteen years.

Comment: You haven't told us how the parameter is supplied, but I'm afraid I can't think of any possible value that you could supply that would make `<CompValue>` true and `<var1>` NaN. Enlighten us please! Also, you've tagged the question both xslt-1.0 and xslt-2.0, and you've left out the version attribute from the question, so you're going out of your way to set us a puzzle...